# Cannot use primefaces extensions with Liferay 6.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6, primefaces-extensions

I'm trying to use the [Primefaces-Extensions](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.primefaces.extensions:primefaces-extensions/1.2.1) library in a Liferay JSF Portlet that is already using primefaces 4.0.

When I include any `pe` component, e.g a `<pe:timer>`, I get this error:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /html/editDoc/myProjects.xhtml @32,39 <pe:timer> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions, but no tag was defined for name: timer
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:423)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:399)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
```

The only component I've managed to use without crashing is pe:ckEditor, which is however rendering as an inputTextarea (no toolbox etc)

I probably did something wrong setting up the primefaces-extensions library, but I don't know where to look.

I'm using:
Liferay 6.2.2 ce
primefaces 4.0
primefaces-extensions 1.2.1 (I guess this is the proper version to work with pf 4.0)

About the steps I followed: (I had a perfectly working pf 4.0 setup)

- Added libs in `[portlet docroot]/WEB-INF/lib/` :

  - primefaces-extensions-1.2.1.jar
  - resources-ckeditor-1.2.1.jar
  - commons-lang3-3.1.jar
  - gson-2.2.4.jar
- Added `xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions` in xhtml file's namespaces

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 
to solve it, you should have 3 jars:
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
primefaces-extensions-2.1.0.jar

!!! you can find in the internet other version of PFE 3..., don't use it, because it's not compatible with the other jars